# Custom List Widget With Scrolling

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am trying to make a program that shows somewhat a thumbnail with image and text.
[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1rD9.png)

But I don't seem to find any way we can make a ListWidget with the design that has both image/text and small description for each item.

[This is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI9J3.png) I tried making a custom widget that has a image with a title and description but I don't know how to add it to a list widget in QTDesiger.

### [Basically instead of this normal list widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRczQ.png)

[I would like somewhat this design list widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI9J3.png)

if any knows how to implement this in Designer or Code. Please assist me. Thank you

Comment: You cannot do this in Designer, if you want to do it using a view widget as QListWidget. You either use [`setItemWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget) with a custom widget (preferably using a class) or use a custom item delegate. In either cases, sorry but we cannot do that for you nor tell you how to do it, as StackOverflow is not a tutorial website. Do some research on the above aspect, then if you still have issues with your attempts, create a new question and provide a [mre] based on your codes.

Comment: Belive me i have done alot of research and I don't seem to find any good resource. the pyqt website is quite confusing and don't provide much of what i need. I did find few youtube video but I wasn't able to get help from that either. I don't want you to do. You can just give me clues like what to search or what to focus on i guess.

Comment: My other approach I was considering was, you know how like a normal list widget where we can add icon and text, I want to do that and know how to do. but the only thing to change form that is How am I able to add style to each for item ( all item has same stylesheet) so for example in the picture i sent above where it just have text list, how can i have (border-radius and background color for the qlistwidget item) when I tried going to properties i was only able to change color. if you can assist me on that, that would be very helpful